# Mysql multiple where conditions

Tags: mysql

I want to search for the all id of table 'szenarien' where sprache='DE' and sprache='EN'. Unfortunately it will not found any result.
I tried a lot with GROUP BY and HAVING but had no success.
Can anybody help me, please.
Thanks a lot.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
   szenarien.id,sprache.sprache 
FROM szenarien 
   LEFT JOIN sprache ON sprache.szenarien_id = szenarien.id 
WHERE sprache.sprache = 'DE' 
  AND sprache.sprache = 'EN'
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What is the issue exactly? Can you give a short example of your table records and how you'd want the results to be? *Please, further clarify 'I want to search for the all id of table'*

Comment: Notice that your query has contradicting condition, `sprache.sprache = 'DE' AND sprache.sprache = 'EN'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT szenarien.id
FROM szenarien 
LEFT JOIN sprache ON sprache.szenarien_id = szenarien.id 
WHERE sprache.sprache in('DE', 'EN')
GROUP BY szenarien.id
HAVING COUNT(distinct sprache.sprache) = 2
```

Comment: It works perfect. Thank you very much for your help.